# Creating multiple objects for HTTP Post

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an API "Device", which doesn't support input of multiple objects..
I want to input a number in a field "number of creating objects"
After pressing the submit button , the application should use my inputs as template and create a list with those objects with just the UUID and name changed.

( Since the API doesn't support input of multiple objects , I wanted to add those objects to a list and then iterate over this list and just call my method `createDevice` for each object in the list. 
)

Since I'm new to thymeleaf and spring I really have no clue how I should realize something like this :

Here is some example Code:

**DeviceController:**

```java
//SIMPLE Controller
private final DeviceService deviceService;
public IndexController(DeviceService deviceService) {
   this.deviceService = deviceService;
}
@GetMapping("/createDevice")
public String createDeviceForm(Model model){
   model.addAttribute("device",new Device());
   return "createDeviceForm";
}
@PostMapping("/createDevice")
public ResponseEntity<Device> processCreateDevice(@ModelAttribute Device device){
   return deviceService.createDevice(device);
}
```

**POJO:**

```java
private Id id;
private CustomerId customerId;
private TenantId tenantId;
private String name;
private String type;
private final static long serialVersionUID = -49143341481414714L;
public Device() {
   this.id = new Id();
   this.tenantId = new TenantId();
   this.customerId = new CustomerId();
   this.setId(this.id);
   this.setTenantId(this.tenantId);
   this.setCustomerId(this.customerId);
}
```

**Service:**

```java
public DeviceServiceImpl(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
   this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Device> createDevice(Device device) {
   String baseLink = "http://localhost:9090/api/device/";
   RequestEntity<Device> requestEntity = null;
   ResponseEntity<Device> responseEntity = null ;
   try {
       requestEntity = RequestEntity.post(new URI(baseLink)).header("X-Authorization","Bearer " + jwtToken)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(deviceWrapper);
   }catch(URISyntaxException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   if(requestEntity != null ) {
       responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, Device.class);
   }
   return responseEntity;
}
```

**Simple thymeleaf template:**

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/createDevice}" th:object="${device}" method="post">
    <p>Device ID <input type="text" th:field="*{id.id}" /></p>
    <p>ENTITYTYPE</p><select th:field="*{id.entityType}">
        <option th:each="type : ${T(com.tomilekar.thingsboard.Model.EntityType).values()}" th:value="${type}" th:text="${typeStat}">Type</option>
    </select>
    <p>Tenant.ID<input type="hidden" th:field="*{tenantId.id}"/></p><p th:text="${device.tenantId.id}"></p>
    <p>Tenant.Entitytype </p> <p th:text="${device.tenantId.entityType}"></p>
    <p>Customer.ID<input type="hidden" th:field="*{customerId.id}"/></p><p th:text="${device.tenantId.id}"></p>
    <p>Customer.Entitytype </p> <p th:text="${device.customerId.entityType}"></p>
    <p>Device.name.id</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <p>Device.Type.id</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{type}"/>
//// ADD button to create multiple objects
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

To create one object at the targetted API is working,
how could I achieve creating multiple objects by adding an number of objects to create?

For the following input :

> Name : TestDevice
>
> UUID: ""692f4a70-5783-11e9-b224-278854131dbb"
>
> Type Device number of objects to create 5

I would like an output :

> TestDevice1-5 692f4a70-5783-11e9-b224-278854[131dbb] -> this part
>   changed for uuid Type Device for each objects.

Any hints are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could do in this way

```
<p>Device.name.id</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{name[0]}"/> //Default
<p>Device.Type.id</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{type[0]}"/> //Default

<p>Device.name.id</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{name[1]}"/> //Generate Dynamically
<p>Device.Type.id</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{type[1]}"/> //Generate Dynamically
.
.
.
<p>Device.name.id</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{name[n]}"/> //Generate Dynamically
<p>Device.Type.id</p> <input type="text" th:field="*{type[n]}"/> //Generate Dynamically
```

Note: Here, these fields need to be generated dynamically on click of ADD button by using either JavaScript Or JQuery.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer , but could you explain me this further? How would i initiliaze my array..?  Would i have in my Controller then something like this : List<Device> myList = new ArrayList<>(); model.addattribute("myList", myList.add(new Device())); or how is this going to work since im getting always the error : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id[0]' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'id[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?